# Android Share Whatsapp onActivityForResult

Tags: android, whatsapp

When I share Text to Whatsapp, How can I know if sharing is successful or canceled?

likes `OnActivityForResult`. I want handy share`s status.

Comment: No, you don't. Not all programs return success or not status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the solution for you, With the help of onActivityResult you can get a callback after sharing anything on WhatsApp. Please use following 
steps 1. Start your intent to receive result from another app

```
  Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
  sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
  sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
  startActivityForResult(sendIntent,1); //1 is request code
```

Step 2.Override onActivityResult in your activity

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext(),"onActivityResult..:",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if(resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), "Got Callback yeppeee...:", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's inside data returned in intent from whatsapp ?

Comment: Not sure, Please verify